# How to use onBlur in flask forms?

Tags: javascript, flask

I would like to start my function simply by changing the field in my form.

I can do it using javascript in my classical HTML input:

```
<p >Enter an email address:</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your email here..." id="myInput" onBlur="getInputValue()">
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Validate</button>

<script>
    function getInputValue(){
        
            // some function

        }
 
</script>
```

right now it's perfectly archived with `onBlur="getInputValue()"` while I don't know how to implement the same in my flask template:

```
        <tr>
            <td>{{form.email.label}}</td>
            <td>{{render_field(form.email)}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">check email</button></td>
        </tr>
```

Where exactly should I put my `onBlur="getInputValue()"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax did the job

```
<td>{{render_field(form.email, onchange="getInputValue()")}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td>{{render_field(form.email(onBlur="getInputValue()"))}}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. Says `"TypeError: 'Markup' object is not callable"`

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747582/wtforms-javascript-pass-onclick-to-wtf-field

Comment: here a full code example https://pythonspot.com/flask-web-forms/        (i edited my answer)

Comment: this a lot - at least there is something to study